# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am implementing revenue monster sdk in my android kotlin project.
This is the sdk github repo link->

> https://github.com/RevenueMonster/rm-kotlin-sdk

This is my code in main activity.

```
 val rsaKeyStr = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"PRIVATEKEY"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
    val config = Config(
    clientID = "CLIENTID",
    clientSecret = "JjMHZCCyzvNlSaRQqwfPlXXDbGoWmAAA",
    privateKey = rsaKeyStr,
    publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" +
    "PUBLICKEY"
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
    sandbox = true
    )
    GlobalScope.launch {
    try {
    val sdk = RevenueMonsterSDK(config)
    val data = WebMobilePaymentRequest(
    order = Order(
    id = "1655811603734186872",
    title = "PaymentTest",
    detail = "JUST A TEST",
    additionalData = "NONE",
    amount = 11,
    currencyType = "MYR"
    ),
    storeId = "1623743430847879711",
    customer = WebMobilePaymentCustomer(
    userId = "12345",
    email = ""
    ),
    type = "MOBILE_PAYMENT",
    layoutVersion = "v3",
    notifyUrl = "https://dev-rm-api.ap.ngrok.io",
    redirectUrl = "https://revenuemonster.my"
    )
    // create quick pay order
    val result = sdk.Payment.webMobilePayment(data)
    Log.e("result::>", result.toString())
    } catch (e: Error) {
    Log.e("ERROR::>", e.toString())
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
    Log.e("Throwable::>", e.toString())
    }
```

Currenlty i am getting this error ->

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000be:ASN.1 encoding
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

---

> Added public key and private key in string format. other operations
> are being performed by sdk itself.

**If anyone has implemented the revenuemonster sdk kindly give idea about the issue.**